# Matching conditions of locally $H^2$ functions to ensure global $H^2$ regularity

Tags: sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ be a non-overlapping partition of a domain $\Omega$. Suppose that a function $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ has $H^2$ regularity on the two subdomains (i.e. $u|_{\Omega_1} \in H^2(\Omega_1)$ and $u|_{\Omega_1} H^2(\Omega_2)$). I would like to prove that, provided that
$$
\begin{split}
[\![ u ]\!] &= u|_{\Omega_1} - u|_{\Omega_2} = 0 \\
[\![ \nabla u ]\!] &= \nabla u|_{\Omega_1} \cdot \mathbf{n}_1 + \nabla u|_{\Omega_2} \cdot \mathbf{n}_2 = 0
\end{split}
$$
then $u$ is globally $H^2$ (i.e. $u \in H^2(\Omega)$).

Do you have any literature reference where this result is proven?

Comment: I don't specifically, but perhaps you can look at how Evans (or Adams and Fournier) constructs the extension operator?

Comment: Imho the assumptions only imply that $\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$ exists in the weak sense. In order to get $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ you need that each partial derivative $\partial_i u$ is in $H^1(\Omega)$, which necessitates $[[ \partial_i u]] =0$.

Comment: If we add the assumption that $\partial\Omega$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$, and that $u = 0$ on $\partial\Omega$, then it follows that $\| u\|_{H^2} \leq C \| \Delta u\|_{L^2}$. So the thesis should hold true in this case. Do you agree with that?